# Сборка Webpack'a работает только на сервере с node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Видел результат сборки вебпака. Где код разделен на модули. В этом коде вызываются require и т.д. И соответственно он не работал в браузере напрямую. Это было SPA. 
Но всегда ли так? Т.е. все что собирает Webpack, работает только на node.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Сам webpack** работает только на машине с node.js.
Обычно это машина разработчика или билд-машина. На продакшн сервере вебпак не нужен.

Результат работы вебпака уже работает там где предназначен работать.

Можно считать, что вебпак в самом простейшем случае преобразует одни js файлы (красивые и удобные) в другие js файлы (легкие). Получившиеся легкие файлы вы и используете как обычно.

Ну то есть в простейшем случае вы из файликов приложения App.js, MyAwesomeComponent.js, MyAwesomeComponent2.js делаете файлик myApp.min.js, содержащий все приложение, и просто подключаете его к странице в духе `<script src = "./myApp.min.js"></script>`

Код который Вы видели в результате сборки вызывал не require из requirejs или еще откуда, а какой-то внутренний метод названный require, определенный в самом этом файлике. То есть если исходники самодостаточны - результат тоже в большинстве случаев самодостаточен.

Разумеется если исходники не предназначены для работы в браузере (требуют node.js рантайма скажем), то в браузере они работать не будут. Если используются какие-то импорты, расположение которых неизвестно вебпаку, то работать тоже не будет (но он об этом предупредит обычно).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Я понял что ошибся) Но разве можно require глобальные модули? Ведь поиск идет в директории и выше и т.д.

Comment: @A.Gusev. Вопрос не понял. Вы ищете шимы? https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules

То есть если модуль живет в глобальной переменной с этим тоже можно работать конечно. Но лишних глобальных переменных лучше не держать, большинство современных библиотек имеют нормальную модульную версию.

Comment: нет, я про это:
_Ну то есть если у вас модулей нету и все через глобальный скоуп общается, то там могут быть проблемы, так как вебпак все таки модули в замыкание оборачивает. Но это проблема архитектуры вашего приложения а не вебпака._

Comment: @A.Gusev это я пояснил слова "в большинстве случаев". Это рабочий случай, просто конфиг чуть побольше придется писать. Удалю навернео чтобы не смущать.

Comment: *"Сам webpack работает только на сервере с node.js."* - некорректное утверждение. Слово "сервере" тут лишнее.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ок, поправил. Просто перефразировал вопрос

Comment: @PavelMayorov Почему лишнее? Разве это не тоже самое что php на сервере nginx?

Comment: @A.Gusev, нет, внес пояснения в первые два абзаца, посмотрите

Comment: @A.Gusev с точки зрения ОС, `node.js` - это утилита командной строки, которая нужна для запуска js-файлов. Ее совершенно не обязательно использовать только на сервере.